# QuickBlox Facebook Chat on iOS - UDID issue

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, quickblox

I use the free QuickBlox Chattar app as the basis for my own chat app:

[Like This.](https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios)

The problem is that, it compiles well, but the chat never starts
because of the error:

"UDID already taken"

Anybody stumbles across such errors using this chat sdk?

Comment: could you share you log here please

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vphajacmnmj6zkz/errors.rtf

Comment: those are among the other errors, the udid error also appears sometimes

Comment: hint:Im only testing in the simulator, because I dont have a device...the code worked few days before

Comment: can't see this message in logs. 
Is this message appears in log? or something else?

Comment: sometimes its the udid message, sometimes the connection error

Comment: the app does not leave the splash screen...also...sometimes its the error with the udid sometimes its something different..thats strange because few days ago it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I removed these two lines and now I don't get that error anymore.

```
extendedAuthRequest.devicePlatorm = DevicePlatformiOS;
extendedAuthRequest.deviceUDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```